# Facebook video upload Exception "(OAuthException - #1) An unknown error has occurred."

Tags: c#, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-c#-sdk, wpf-4.5

My WPF application i am using [**facebook C# SDK**](http://www.nuget.org/packages/facebook) to upload videos to facebook wall. From last two days, when i upload video through my application, SDK returns **"(OAuthException - #1) An unknown error has occurred."** exception, but my video file uploaded to my facebook wall.

I tried the following way to resolve this problem,
    1) Created new appliction for new AppID and AppSecretID.
    2) Change authentication permissions **(current permissions provided user_about_me,read_stream,publish_stream,user_photos)**
    3) Clear the existing application permission in my facebook account
    4) Creating new facebook application and upload a video file.
But nothing helps me. Here is the code i used to upload video,

```
public Task<bool> FacebookPost(string message,Stream videoFileStream)
    {
        bool result = false;
          try
            {
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(_localSettings.FBAccessToken))
                {
                    _fbClient.AccessToken = "ACCESS_TOKEN";
                    _fbClient.AppId = "APP_ID";
                    _fbClient.AppSecret = "APP_SECRET";

                    var media = new FacebookMediaStream { ContentType = "video/mp4", FileName = "TestVideo.mp4" }.SetValue(fbStream);
                    dynamic parameters = new ExpandoObject();
                    parameters.Title = "Sample Video";
                    parameters.description = message;
                    parameters.source = media;
                    var uploadResult = await _fbClient.PostTaskAsync("me/videos", parameters);
                    result = uploadResult != null;                       
                }
            }
            catch (FacebookOAuthException ex)
            {
                result = false;
            }
            return result;
    }
```

Any help it will would be appreciated. Thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 1):

Check that https://developers.facebook.com/x/bugs/247807142061930/ Appears to be a known bug